# How to extract selected key and value from nested dictionary object in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list `example_list` contains two dict objects, it looks like this:

```
[
        {
            "Meta": {
                "ID": "1234567",
                "XXX": "XXX"
            },
            "bbb": {
                "ccc": {
                    "ddd": {
                        "eee": {
                            "fff": {
                                "xxxxxx": "xxxxx"
                            },
                            "www": [
                                {
                                    "categories": {
                                        "ppp": [
                                            {
                                                "content": {
                                                    "name": "apple",
                                                    "price": "0.111"
                                                },
                                                "xxx: "xxx"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "date": "A2020-01-01"
                               }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Meta": {
                "ID": "78945612",
                "XXX": "XXX"
            },
            "bbb": {
                "ccc": {
                    "ddd": {
                        "eee": {
                            "fff": {
                                "xxxxxx": "xxxxx"
                            },
                            "www": [
                                {
                                    "categories": {
                                        "ppp": [
                                            {
                                                "content": {
                                                    "name": "banana",
                                                    "price": "12.599"
                                                },
                                                "xxx: "xxx"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "date": "A2020-01-01"
                               }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

now I want to filter the items and only keep `"ID": "xxx"` and the correspoding value for `"price": "0.111"`, expected result can be something similar to :

`[{"ID": "1234567", "price": "0.111"}, {"ID": "78945612", "price": "12.599"}]`
or something like `{"1234567":"0.111", "78945612":"12.599" }`

Here's what I've tried:

```
map_list=[]
map_dict={}
for item in example_list:
   #get 'ID' for each item in 'meta'
   map_dict['ID'] = item['meta']['ID']
   
   # get 'price'
   data_list = item['bbb']['ccc']['ddd']['www']
   for data in data_list:
      for dataitem in data['categories']['ppp']
         map_dict['price'] = item["content"]["price"]
         map_list.append(map_dict)

print(map_list)
```

The result for this doesn't look right, feels like the item isn't iterating properly, it gives me result:

```
[{"ID": "78945612", "price": "12.599"}, {"ID": "78945612", "price": "12.599"}]
```

It gave me duplicated result for the second ID but where is the first ID?
Can someone take a look for me please, thanks.

Update:
From some comments from another question, I understand the reason for the output keeps been overwritten is because the key name in the `dict` is always the same, but I'm not sure how to fix this because the key and value needs to be extracted from different level of for loops, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why is your "list of ID" made up of a number and a string?

Comment: Why not create a single dictionary mapping ID to price?

Comment: Hi, what I meant is after I got the expected list, such as : `[{"ID": "1234567", "price": "0.111"}, {"ID": "78945612", "price": "12.599"}]`, and then I can create another function, it takes a list of IDs as input and return the coresponding prices, does this make sense?

Comment: `Why not create a single dictionary mapping ID to price` - you mean something like `{"1234567": "0.111", "78945612": "12.599"}`? how can I achieve this? Thanks. @ScottHunter

Comment: Please post your actual code & data; what you have posted have numerous errors each.

Comment: if there are more than 1 "www" and/or more than 1 "ppp" which price do you seek? Are all the keys guaranteed to exist?

Comment: @JonSG Hi yes, all the keys are existed, and there's only one `www` but with multiple `categories`, and I only want to keep the `categories` with the latest date for `date` (i.e.: "A2020-01-01"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Scott Hunter has mentioned, you need to create a new `map_dict` everytime you are trying to do this. Here is a quick fix to your solution (I am sadly not able to test it right now, but it seems right to me).

```
map_list=[]
for item in example_list:
   # get 'price'
   data_list = item['bbb']['ccc']['ddd']['www']
   for data in data_list:
      for dataitem in data['categories']['ppp']:
         map_dict={}
         map_dict['ID'] = item['meta']['ID']
         map_dict['price'] = item["content"]["price"]
         map_list.append(map_dict)

print(map_list)
```

But what are you doing here is that you are basically just "forcing" your way through ... I recommend you to take a break and check out somekind of tutorial, which will help you to understand how it really works in the back-end. This is how I would have written it:

```
list_dicts = []
for example in example_list:
    for www in item['bbb']['ccc']['ddd']['www']:
        for www_item in www:
            list_dicts.append({
                     'ID': item['meta']['ID'], 
                     'price': www_item["content"]["price"]
            })
```

Good luck with this problem and hope it helps :)

Comment: if I understand it correctly, then yes (also if you know that its just a single `www` then that 1 forloop is redundant)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new dictionary for `map_dict` for each ID.

Comment: can you provide some example code please?

Comment: Just move your initialization of `map_dict`  into the outer loop.