# Adding items in a dictionary but the precious value seems to be overwritten via for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list `sample_list` like this:

```
[
        {
            "Meta": {
                "ID": "1234567",
                "XXX": "XXX"
            },
            "bbb": {
             "color":red"
        },
        {
            "Meta": {
                "ID": "78945612",
                "XXX": "XXX"
            },
            "bbb": {
               "color":"blue"
        }
    ]
```

now I want to extract the field "ID" and the values then put them in a `dict` object, I tried:

```
init_dict = {}
for item in sample_list:  
   init_dict['ID'] = item['Meta']['ID']
   print(init_dict)
```

This returns:

```
{'ID': '1234567'}
{'ID': '78945612'}
```

Seems like the second value overwrite the first one, if I print from outside of the iteration:

```
init_dict = {}
for item in sample_list:
   init_dict['ID'] = item['Meta']['ID']
print(init_dict)
```

This only return the last value:

```
{'ID': '78945612'}
```

Combining with the comment below, I realise the logic here is wrong, since the key name is always 'ID', I'VE updated the example in the question, can we take the value for `ID` as the new key and taking the value for `color` as the new value?
Expected output is something like

```
{'1234567':'red', '78945612':'blue'}
```

can someone help please? Thanks.

Comment: You reset `init_dict` on each iteration of the loop.  When the `print` is inside the loop, you get to see the current value right before it gets reset.  However, even if you don't reset the dict every time, you would *still* overwrite the value because they all use the same key `'ID'`.

Comment: give us the  output you want to have

Comment: @0x5453 Thanks, I removed the `init_dict` out of the for loop, as you said, the value is still gets overwritten, I updated the example in the question, can the solution be something like take the value for `ID`as the new key and taking the value for `color` as the new vaue? Something like `{'1234567':'red'}`

Comment: @virxen Hi I've updated my question, thanks

Comment: @JonSG Hi I've updated my question, thanks

Comment: @Cecilia I've updated my answer to match your new question, should work as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the second line of a for loop. What you are doing is that you are creating a dictionary in this forloop. In any other language, you would get a syntax error, because you are trying to access un-initialised variable (in this case `init_dict`) (in this case, if sample_list is empty, you will get an error that init_dict does not exist)

```
for item in sample_list:
   init_dict = {}     // here
   init_dict['ID'] = item['Meta']['ID']
print(init_dict)
```

Simple fix is to move it outside of a for loop

```
init_dict = {}

for item in sample_list:
   init_dict['ID'] = item['Meta']['ID']

print(init_dict)
```

color edit:

```
init_dict = {}

for item in sample_list:
   init_dict[item['Meta']['ID']] = item['bbb']['color']

print(init_dict)
```

Here you can see that you can use anything as a key, but be careful, the key has to unique, so in this case, ID is a very good key, but if there is a chance that you can get a duplicate ID, I recommend you to find a better key. Also, if you do not need the dictionary in first place, I recommend using just a list of tuples (i.e -> `[(key, val), (key2, val2), (key3, val3)]`. The list has no problem with duplicities

Comment: Hi I tried to move the `init_dict = {}` out but the result is actually still the same, because the key in `init_dict` is always the same, it gets overwritten, I've updated my question, please could you take a look, thanks.

Comment: @Cecilia hi, I have edited my answer, please take a look :)

Comment: also, next time please create a new question and do not just edit the current question, it can create a confusion, since few people here have already answered and you asked a different question that someone else might know how to answer, yet they already marked this question as "seen" :)

Comment: Thanks, I do have another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68021167/how-to-extract-selected-key-and-value-from-nested-dictionary-object-in-a-list, so instead of using the data 'color' from the same `item` which can be achieved in one `for loop`, this case is a bit more complicated, could you pease take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @StyleZ Edits and clarifications are import parts of asking and answering questions. If the question is not clear, ask for clarification before answering.

Comment: @Cecilia gonna take a look if I know how to answer :)

Comment: @JonSG the problem was that the question has changed, the original question was asking something else :) but thats not important anymore

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are looping, you are just overwriting the same dictionary. Now, it prints both the elements in the first method because your print statement is inside the for loop. In the second method, your print statement is outside the for loop. So, it prints only the last value that you gave which is `78945612`.

Here you are just overwriting the same dictionary. So, every time you change the `ID`, it just stores the last value that you gave.

Comment: Thanks, I just realised this, so I updated my question, instead of using the same key name , it's probably better to have a mapping relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append to your dictionary. The line `init_dict = {}` resets your dictionary. Instead you should do:

```
init_dict = {'ID':[]}
for item in sample_list:
    init_dict['ID'].append(item['Meta']['ID'])
print(init_dict)
```

To satisfy the request you made in a comment, you can do this to use the value as a key and then add a colour:

```
init_dict = {}
for item in sample_list:
    init_dict[item['Meta']['ID']] = "red"
```

Comment: Hi the solution here has hard-coded 'red' which I can't do this, my data is very big I can;t specify them manually, it has to be fetched from the data.

Comment: You can replace the `"red"` with whatever code you use to retrieve the colour, this was just to show an example of using the value as a key for the new dict.

Comment: Hi thanks, I think the difficult here is how to replace the value 'red', because the value I need to retrieve wi;; from another for loop and I can't get access to this upper level

Comment: You could always set `init_dict[item['Meta']['ID']] = ""` and then from your other section where your colour is decided then do `init_dict[ID] = color`.

Comment: Just seen your most recent edit, disregard this.

Comment: Hi sorry this example is a simple case, I was thinking about the situation in this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68021167/how-to-extract-selected-key-and-value-from-nested-dictionary-object-in-a-list, so instead of using the data 'color' from the same `item` which can be achieved in one `for loop`, this case is a bit more complicated, any hint will be appreciated, thanks.